# How to move Label text smoothly using Timer?

Tags: c#, label

In C# WinForm application, I have a `Label` control, and I want to move its text from right to left when the text is not fit in the size.

I got my text to slide from right to left using `Timer` but it doesn't move smoothly because I think each alphabet's width differs (like `i`'s width is much shorter than that of `w`, etc.) This looks very bad and I attached a *gif* below for you to see. It says **Why won't this text move smoothly?** As you can see, it is very difficult to read because it moves sometimes a lot, and sometimes a little.

[image: Why won't this text move smoothly?]

The width and height of the `Label` control are fixed and not to be changed.

Here is my code:

```
 /* Timer event to move the text from right to left. */
 /* The name of the Label control is myLabel. */
 private void MoveLabelText_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.myLabel.Text = this.myLabel.Text.Substring(1, this.myLabel.Text.Length - 1) + this.myLabel.Text.Substring(0, 1);
 }
```

Can anyone please give me advice on what I can do to fix this?
Or is there any other way than using Timer if that's easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend instead that you don't edit the text.  Have the label instead with a constant text and have it be inside a Panel object.  Then, move the label's position so certain parts of the label are visible in the panel.  I think you'll get a better experience.  You'll be changing the Left coordinate instead of the text.  The label will be wider than the Panel.

Source Code for Designer

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Me.Panel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Timer1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer(Me.components)
        Me.Panel1.SuspendLayout()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Panel1
        '
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
        Me.Panel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(279, 90)
        Me.Panel1.Name = "Panel1"
        Me.Panel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 100)
        Me.Panel1.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(177, 35)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(291, 13)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Label1.Text = "rewrewtewerewrewtjoitjrewoirewjtewotjweotirjewotijwertjewirtj"
        '
        'Timer1
        '
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Panel1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.Panel1.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.Panel1.PerformLayout()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents Panel1 As Panel
    Friend WithEvents Label1 As Label
    Friend WithEvents Timer1 As Timer
End Class
```

Source Code for VB File

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X - 1, Label1.Location.Y)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Picture of the Label Starting To Right and Intentionally Cut Off
   [image: Picture of the Label Starting To Right and Intentionally Cut Off]